# Ajax PHP wont retrieve address bar variable

Tags: php, ajax

My current website address reads: www.mysite.com/index.php?user=123

I click a link to active an ajax page to open. The ajax page contains the following:

```
$usernum = $_GET["user"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE user = $usernum");
```

This produces an error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\social2\profile\indexBasics.php on line 29
```

No error ocurrs if I hard code in a user number though, it just refuses to get the address bar variable.

Help? Advice?

----- ADDED INFO ------

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var basics = document.getElementById('basics'),
        favorites = document.getElementById('favorites');

    basics.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexBasics');
        var otherClasses = favorites.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            basics.className = 'statusOptionActive';
            favorites.className = 'statusOption';
        }
    }

    favorites.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexFav');        
        var otherClasses = basics.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            favorites.className = 'statusOptionActive';
            basics.className = 'statusOption';
        }
    }

    function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("centreCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","../profile/" + pageName + ".php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Personally, I would avoid using `mysql_query` like that without escaping the input. I suggest PDOStatmements. Very safe, and easy to use.

Comment: Your current PHP code has a blatant SQL injection vulnerability that would be trivial for anyone to exploit. Please learn about both sanitizing user input and parameterized queries.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that you are on `www.mysite.com/index.php?user=123` when you click on your button (or whatever fire the AJAX event), you will load a different URL, which can be something like `www.mysite.com/myajaxpage.php`.

In that case, you may have forget to pass the user parameter to your AJAX request. So you can't access to `$_GET['user']` in `myajaxpage.php` because it isn't defined in your URL.

#### Code example

<strike>If you're using jQuery, you can do this trick:</strike>

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

// ....

$.post('myajaxpage.php', {'user': $.urlParam('user')}, function(data) {
   // your stuff
});
```

EDIT: The author uses Vanilla JS, so this example was just pointless.

Comment: This is very confusing to me. My javascript knowledge is slim to none. Is it not possible just to extend the current PHP to get the address variable?

Comment: Can you show me your ajax call (where you're calling the second PHP page)

Comment: I've added it to my original question for you. It in there somewhere

Comment: A quick way would be to modify your call by : `xmlhttp.open("GET","../profile/" + pageName + ".php?user=".$_GET['user'],true);`. With the `?user=...` added, you will be able to get the desired output.

Comment: That actually stops the ajax working completely. I think that has mixed PHP with javascript hasn't it?

Comment: In fact, it's `xmlhttp.open("GET","../profile/" + pageName + ".php?user=<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>,true);`. Sorry for my mistake. This line works only if you're JS is inside your index.php however.